How to recognize box overflow in weasyprint?
is there a way for the caller/parent process when rendering HTML into PDF, either with the weasyprint command line or the python API, to recognize whether everything went well and all text became fully visible where it belongs, or whether there was a box overflow, e.g. by too much text or a too large font?
I'd expect some error message, hint, return value, indicating that the rendered result is not good.

You completely misunderstood the question.
I'm talking about the HTML part, when a text does not fit into a container like a div, either because the text is too long, or the font size is too big. This has nothing to do with PDF, because it's a problem occuring during the HTML interpretation.
